# Android Studio 1.4 Code Coverage

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm having some trouble to get code coverage on my project. My unit and UI tests are placed on the "androidTest" folder. Tests run smoothly but when I try to get code coverage (both running with coverage or ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport from CLI) I get different type of errors.

Here's my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    jacoco {
        version "0.7.1.201405082137"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v0.9.3'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.5'
    compile 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

    testCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to set code coverage for both InstrumentationTestCase and ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 placed on "androidTest" folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i setup jacoco in my build.gradle (app) file. And it worked fine without any issues. And the setup was for unit test using JUnit 4.12. Hope this helps

```
jacoco {
      toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

def coverageSourceDirs = {
         '../app/src'
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport, dependsOn: "test"){
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"
    classDirectories = fileTree(
          dir: '../app/build/intermediates/classes',
          excludes: ['**/R.class',
                     '**/R$.class',
                     '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                     '**/BuildConfig.*',
                     '**/Manifest*.*']
    )
   additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
   sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
   executionData = files('../app/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')

   reports {
      xml.enabled = true
      html.enabled = true
   }
}
```